# Changing a folder name that has a space in it

Tags: command-line, directory, rename

I need to Change a folder name `Word Press` into `wordpress`.
It gives an error because I have mistakenly written the folder name in two parts, which is not recognized as one name.
What can I do terminal prompt wise, please?

Answer (score 8):

You need to **escape** the space in name.
Type

```
mv "Word Press" wordpress
```

or

```
mv Word\ Press wordpress
```

Comment: It says file cannot be read. Directory or folder not found.(translation)

Comment: Does the folder need to be active when doing this?

Comment: If you get a message "directory not found", you need to use the correct path to the directory. The commands I wrote will work only if your current directory is the parent directory of "Word Press". You should either change to that directory or use full paths in the command.

Answer (score 2):

To **automatically** remove spaces in all file/directory names in the current working directory, you can use `rename`(*needs installing*) like so:

```
rename -n 's/ //g' *
```

**Notice**: `-n` is for a dry-run ... Remove it when satisfied with the output and rerun to actually do the renaming.

Or you can use a `bash` loop like so:

```bash
for f in *; do [[ "$f" =~ " " ]] && echo mv -n -- "$f" "${f// /}"; done
```

**Notice**: `echo` is for a dry-run ... Remove it when satisfied with the output and rerun to actually do the renaming.